# Scale that resizes with zoom (threejs + orthographic view)

Tags: three.js, scale, orthographic

I'd like to add a scale in my scene, then resize the scale on zoom.

I work with an orthographic camera and the trackball orthographic controller.

The scale lets the user know the dimensions of the image he is looking at - (see green scale on the left of the screenshots)

Before zoom:
[image]
After zoom:
[image]

Which would be the best approach with THREEJS?
- have a 'scale' object in the scene and resize it somehow?
- overlay a div on top of the renderer and also resize it somehow?
- overlay a new renderer?

Is there any example of such implementation somewhere already?

Best,